# Two dimensional dictionary in CLI/C++

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to store data in a two dimensional dictionary with the programming language CLI/C++.

However, I am facing problems adding something into them.

This is my attempt which works in C#:

```
 Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> MyDictionary;
 if (!MyDictionary.ContainsKey(100))
    MyDictionary.Add(100, new Dictionary<int, string>());

 MyDictionary[100][1234] = "Hello World";
```

Now - my CLI/C++ attempt:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, String^>^>^ MyDictionary = gcnew Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, String^>^>();
//ContainsKey check here
MyDictionary[100][1234] = "Hello World"; //<--- ERROR
MyDictionary[100, 1234] = "Hello World"; //<--- ERROR
```

It seems that you don't add something into the Dictionary using [][]. I saw people using [100, 1234] instead of [100][1234] but that doesn't work either.

Error:

```
 function "System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<TKey, TValue>::default[TKey]::set [with TKey=int, TValue=System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<int, String ^> ^]" cannot be called with the given argument list
        argument types are: (int, int, String^)
        object type is: System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<int, System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary<int, String ^> ^> ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.  Note that the code compiles just fine.  This is a bug in the IntelliSense parser.  It has several, the EDG front-end was originally designed to parse C++ and isn't exactly bug-free when it needs to tackle C++/CLI code.

You probably don't want to ignore these false diagnostics, they are pretty annoying.  The least painful workaround is:

```
   auto item = MyDictionary[100];
   item[1234] = "Hello World";
```

Makes no difference in speed after the optimizer is done with it.